# How to automatically insert and parse xml elements using any script(python/shell)?

Tags: python, shell

This is extension of question asked in link:-
[How to insert sub-elements of xml tag at specific position using python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51008621/how-to-insert-sub-elements-of-xml-tag-at-specific-position-using-python-script)

It is working fine if I use python 3 where I have Element Tree. If I don't have python 3(as current version i am using is 2.6, can't upgrade) how can i write to xml files with xml_declaration flag true? 
It seems xml flag is getting removed when parsing.
Basically, I am getting error while parsing the xml:-

```
 org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:config.xml; lineNumber: 1; 
 columnNumber: 1; file:config.xml<Line 1, Column 1>: XML-20108: (Fatal Error) Start of root element expected.[[
    at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLError.flushErrorHandler(XMLError.java:425)
    at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLError.flushErrors1(XMLError.java:290)
    at oracle.xml.parser.v2.NonValidatingParser.parseRootElement(NonValidatingParser.java:476)
    at oracle.xml.parser.v2.NonValidatingParser.parseDocument(NonValidatingParser.java:417)
    at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:287)
    at oracle.ossmgmt.common.util.xml.XMLUtilityParser.validate(XMLUtilityParser.java:141)
    at oracle.ossmgmt.common.util.xml.XMLUtilityParser.initParse(XMLUtilityParser.java:256)
    at oracle.ossmgmt.common.util.xml.XMLUtility.initParse(XMLUtility.java:381)
```

I also tried using lxml :-

```
from lxml import etree as ET
param1='conf.xml'
tree = ET.parse(param1)
print(ET.getroot())
param2='Target'
target = tree.find(param2)
#print target.tag,target.attrib
seq = 'Attribute NAME="EFG" VALUE="1234"'
param3 = seq
temp = ET.Element(param3)
temp.tail = '\n'
target.insert(4,temp)
tree.write(param1, encoding='utf-8', xml_declaration=True)
```

but here I am getting error as:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "b.py", line 10, in <module>
    temp = ET.Element(param3)
File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 2346, in lxml.etree.Element 
(src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:46617)
File "apihelpers.pxi", line 113, in lxml.etree._makeElement 
(src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:10475)
File "apihelpers.pxi", line 1405, in lxml.etree._tagValidOrRaise 
(src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:21541)
ValueError: Invalid tag name u'Attribute NAME="EFG" VALUE="1234"'
```

Comment: Currently I am doing this
out = open(param1,'w')
out.write('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>'+'\n')
tree._write(out, tree._root, 'utf-8', {})

Comment: I tried with lxml but got an error.

Comment: @snakecharmerb - Update the question with errors

Comment: `temp = ET.Element('Attribute NAME="EFG" VALUE="1234"')`. That does not seem like a valid string to pass to the ET.Element constructor.

Comment: @PAckerman - It works fine when you use -

    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
    import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
Only issue was xml_declaration not defined, so using lxml.
Can you suggest how to use it ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure what your intended end-structure is, but:

```
seq = 'Attribute NAME="EFG" VALUE="1234"'
param3 = seq
temp = ET.Element(param3)
```

Should most likely be something like:

```
seq = 'Attribute' 
#Create element <Attribute>
temp = ET.Element(seq)
#Set attributes of <Attribute>
temp.set("NAME","EFG") 
temp.set("VALUE","1234")
```

Comment: This works... Thanks....but actually my intended end-structure is like this:-
<Attribute NAME="IPAddress" VALUE="((host=localhost,ip=222.2.2.2,port=22,community=public),(host=abc.com,ip=222.2.2.2,port=22,community=public))" />
for which I was trying like this
seq = 'Attribute NAME="IPAddress" VALUE="((host=localhost,ip=222.2.2.2,port=22,community=public),(host=localhost,ip={0},port=22,community=public))"'.format(host1)

Can you please suggest for this also?

Comment: @P Ackerman - How can I make it compatible for both python 2 and python 3?

Comment: your solution works but I am still not able to understand why exception still occuring:-
config.xml<Line 1, Column 1>: XML-20108: (Fatal Error) Start of root element expected.[[
        at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLError.flushErrorHandler(XMLError.java:425)
        at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLError.flushErrors1(XMLError.java:290)
        at oracle.xml.parser.v2.NonValidatingParser.parseRootElement(NonValidatingParser.java:476)

Comment: @Pyjava 
You would just change this line:
`temp.set("VALUE","1234")`
to
`temp.set("VALUE","((host=localhost,ip=222.2.2.2,port=22,community=public),(host=localhost,ip={0},port=22,community=public))".format(host1))`

Comment: @P Ackerman - This is fine but how to get rid of xml error. It seems 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> is getting removed while inserting and probably structure also gets distorted which is making xml invalid.
Above solution works but not parser expected under root for python 2.6

Comment: Structure of xml is below:-

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Targets version="0.0">
 <Target TYPE="Cell" NAME="PyJava">
  <Attribute NAME="maxVSlot" VALUE="8"></Attribute>
  <Attribute NAME="accessLevelPerm" VALUE="remoteLoginEnabled"></Attribute>
  <Attribute NAME="id" VALUE="2018"></Attribute>
  <Attribute NAME="maxFldVSlot" VALUE="8"></Attribute>
 </Target>
</Targets>

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're saying, but I would recommend writing to a second file rather than to the original. The way your code is set up should not do anything to the opening xml declaration tag.